# In a firestore collection, how would I prevent an auth user from adding too many documents in a collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection in a firestore.  There are rules in place that allow users to add documents in a collection.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: false
      allow write: false
      allow update: false
      allow delete: false
    }

    match /users/{userId}/widgets/{widgetId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid == userId
      allow update: if request.auth.uid == userId
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == userId
    }
  }
}
```

How do I prevent users from adding more than 100 documents?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple rule that can be used to limit the number of documents in a collection.  You will have to use another document to keep a running total as they're added, then check the contents of that document in the rules to determine if the limit is going to be exceeded.

Alternatively, you can have the client call a server-side function to write the document, and it can check (in its own code) if the collection will get too big.